# Is there a way to update user info with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a personal project and stumbled upon this problem. I've managed to make my (steam)users save to mongodb through mongoose. Right now I've made it `.save()` a new user only when it's not already found in the DB. But what if someone changes their steam nickname or picture and log-in again, they will have the ones I initially saved. Any way to only update changes to a user in the database?
thanks.

```
app.get('/auth/steam/return',
  passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    const user = new User({ //create user object on schema
      name: req.user.displayName,
      steam64: req.user.id
    });
    User.findOne({steam64: req.user.id}, function(err, user1){ //try to find user by id in DB
      if(err){ // catch error
        console.log(err);
      }
      if(user1){console.log('user found, proceeding...')} // user was found in DB
      if(!user1){ //user not found, writing to DB
        console.log('no user found with that id, writing.')
          user.save()
          .then((result) => {
            console.log('user saved successfully !')
          })
          .catch((err) => { // catch & print error
            console.log(err);
          });
      }   
    });
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `findOneAndUpdate()` with option `{upsert:true}` and also `new : true` to return the document after update was applied.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({steam64: req.user.id},{
     name: req.user.displayName,
     steam64: req.user.id
},{new : true, upsert: true})
```

Comment: show the result of console.log(req.user.displayName)

Comment: also to return the document after update was applied use `new: true` like my answer

Comment: it works on the second log-in. So i am logged out right now, I change my name in steam, I log-in into the website, DB name stays the same, log-out, log-in and only then it updates.

Comment: here is a video example : https://youtu.be/e9Vkc5ztKaQ

Comment: do you use new: true ??I've updated my answer

Comment: sorry, I did not see it. It does work now ! but the console.log(result.name); is still one iteration before. Could you please explain the logic behind this new:true ? thanks.

Comment: when you update a document by default return old document, with new: true, return document after update